# C# DateTime.Parse efficiently time with hour/min/sec/milis/micro/nano seconds

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

From third party I'm getting this string that I'd like to convert to DateTime:
**"13 NOV 2018 16:08:52:000:000:000"**
I've tried those options but `FormatException` thrown:

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact("12 NOV 2018 16:08:52:000:000:000", 
                           "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff:ffffff:fffffffff", 
                                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

And the same exception when I've used this:

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact("12 NOV 2018 16:08:52:000:000:000",
                            "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Is there a clean way to parse it as is or, I need to use a dirty way such `string.Split(new []{':'})`?

Note:

- For my business needs, I don't need the part of micro/nano seconds.
- since this parsing operation occurs many times in a second, the efficiency is a key factor.

**Update**

I chose the @Tim's suggestion to do string manipulation:

```
string date = "12 NOV 2018 16:08:52:000:000:000";
date = date.Remove(date.Remove(date.LastIndexOf(':')).LastIndexOf(':'));
DateTime result = System.DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The reasons:

- I can't promise the structure of the `date` string, since it comes from third party. So it will be very dangerous to use the format pattern `dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff:fff:fff`
- As @Jeroen Mostert wrote the usage of string splitting is not a key factor when you use `DateTime.ParseExact()`

> Also, if you really think efficiency is so important, don't assume any single call to DateTime.ParseExact will be "fast", or that any string splitting you do will be a bottleneck.

Comment: are the micro and nano seconds always going to be zeros?

Comment: If the efficiency is such a key factor, consider solving the problem at the root and making the system spit out a format that's trivial to parse anywhere -- say, absolute ticks. I know the answer to such things is typically "no, I can't change any of that", but then again, the problems of the real world are those you left with when you refuse to apply their effective solutions, so it's always worth trying. Also, if you really think efficiency is so important, don't assume any single call to `DateTime.ParseExact` will be "fast", or that any string splitting you do will be a bottleneck.

Comment: Fyi, i have edited [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53280629/284240) to show a way to remove the unnecessary part.

Comment: @themehio Since it comes from third party, I can't promise the micro/nano will always be zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, isn't it simply this?

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact("12 NOV 2018 16:08:52:000:000:000", 
                           "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff:fff:fff", 
                           System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

This works if all groups of `f` have the same values, so for example all `0` or `123`.

Tbh, i don't understand why you think that `fff:ffffff:fffffffff` matches `000:000:000`

> For my business needs, I don't need the part of micro/nano seconds.

You could make your second format working by cutting off the micro/nano part:

```
string date = "12 NOV 2018 16:08:52:000:000:000";
date = date.Remove(date.Remove(date.LastIndexOf(':')).LastIndexOf(':'));
DateTime result = System.DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Of course this assumes that there are always at least two colons. It's obvious that you need a `try-catch` to log invalid values and to continue with the next one.

Comment: It seems the three groups of f's are processed as duplicates, which means that it will only parse a string ending with something like `:443:443:443`, if even one of those groups differ it complains with "DateTime pattern 'f' appears more than once with different values."

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: yes, seems so, learned something new again :)

Comment: Why not simply `.Substring(0, "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff".Length)`? The initial part is fixed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: the format could contain [special or formatting characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#character-literals) like `'`. Truncating the unnecessary part from the end is safer.

Comment: What format? Not `dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff` under the invariant culture... Obviously if the format actually changes the string used to parse it will have to change along with it. If the format *does* change, maybe they can take the opportunity to cut off those extra parts we don't need, making the whole issue moot. :-)

Comment: @JeroenMostert: for example: `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("13/11/2018", "dd'/'MM'/'yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. The format can be longer than the date-string. The truncate-unnecessary-nanos-from-end approach would not break so easily then.

Comment: In which case you'd use `.Substring(0, "dd/MM/yyyy")`. I see the confusion: I just used the format string as a shorthand to avoid a magic constant for the length and make it clear where our knowledge of the length was coming from; I wasn't suggesting the format string should always be used literally in the `Substring`. Whether assuming a prefix length or assuming "the last two parts with colons can always safely be cut off" is robust in the face of changes is a matter of opinion, I suppose. This is either covered by tests, or something that will fail quickly when it's not.

Comment: @TimSchmelter "Tbh, i don't understand why you think that fff:ffffff:fffffffff matches 000:000:000". You are 100% right. It was my mistake - thought that the 'f' represents the power of the part need to be represented in the format.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: when something comes from a third party you can't change it and it might change in future. Then i prefer a little more robust approach over a constant length sub-string. In this case it might not make a difference but maybe the format itself could be provided. Then you can't rely on the constant length (or the format-length).

Comment: To be fair, if I wanted to add robustness to this, I'd do a preliminary regex match to verify it's still what we're expecting, and if not, complain. The remaining implementation is then free to go about it in whatever way we prefer. The alternative ("I assume this, but not this") makes it harder to think about when garbage could silently slip into the system.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: why regex and not `DateTime.TryParseExact`?

Comment: Because this format, as we've established, can't actually be parsed with a vanilla `TryParseExact` without pre-processing, otherwise there'd be no problem in the first place! A regex would tell me 1) yes, this can be parsed correctly with our pre-processing and `TryParseExact` together or 2) no, it can't, and I don't know how things get screwed up and what `TryParseExact` will be asked to work on when we start cutting off parts, so stop. (You may call me paranoid; we could assume we'll never end up with something that "accidentally" looks correct. If I'm going for robustness, I stop assuming.)

Answer (score 1):

Not an exact answer

```
System.DateTime.ParseExact("25 NOV 2018 16:08:52:000:000:000",
                            "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff:fff:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Things to consider: count of input string (000) should match with format(fff),

000 = fff good

00 = fff not good

000 = ff not good

You may need to manipulate input date string before trying to parse.

See this for more information regarding use of format specifier (fff)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

.NET Fiddle:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/5UxCkd

Answer (score 0):

I think that having same format for :fff is a key factor here

`System.DateTime.ParseExact("12 NOV 2018 16:08:52:000:000:000","dd MMM yyyy H:mm:ss:fff:fff:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` seems to work

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZAtchu example code